# Facebook API Android Authentication used for the Web API

Tags: android, facebook, api, oauth-2.0

I'd like to use the Android SDK for the Facebook API.  I'm having no issues with retrieving the access_token, described here: [Retrieve Auth Key][1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android

I can also authenticate just fine with Facebook using the Android SDK.

On the Web end, I'm having no problem authenticating with [this,](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE)  Found on [FB](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

My problem is I need to be able to issue the Web API authentication using the information I get from the Android SDK.

Is this possible?  I'm having trouble finding any information on how to do this.

Thanks!

--Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott,

Are you retrieving the access token when the user authenticates from the FB Android SDK?

Once you have that access token, no matter where you get it, it's good for up to 30 minutes (soon to be 3 weeks).

So you can make any Graph call you like about the user as long as you have the proper permissions from the allow.

something along these lines:
facebook.request("me");  // to get the current logged in users info..

-J

Comment: Thanks Joey,

Yes, I'm using the FB Android SDK.  Thanks for your help! That makes sense.  

Do you know of anyway to be able to access the user's content for longer than 30 minutes?  With twitter and LinkedIn I can have permission until it's revoked, but is that not available for facebook?

Comment: Well - currently there is a permission called offline_access which allows you access to a users data indefinitely.