# How to retrieve Twitter and facebook Authentication and Token through Android's Account Manager classes

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, twitter

I want to retrieve token via      Account Manager classes. Here is sample code that works for twitter but not for facebook plz help me.

```
public class AccountManagerActivity extends Activity {

    AccountManager mAccountManager;
    AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> c;
    String token;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] acc = mAccountManager.getAccounts();
        for (int i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Account name==" + acc[i].name);
            System.out.println("Account Type==" + acc[i].type);
        }
        AuthenticatorDescription[] ad = mAccountManager.getAuthenticatorTypes();
        for (int i = 1; i < ad.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("AuthenticatorDescription==" + ad[i].type);
        }


        tokenForTwitter();
        tokenForFacebook();
    }

    private void tokenForFacebook() {
        Account[] accts = mAccountManager
                .getAccountsByType("com.facebook.auth.login");
        int i = 0;
        if (accts.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("here");
            Account acct = accts[0];
            c = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(acct,
                    "com.facebook.auth.token" , null,
                    this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                            try {
                                Bundle b = arg0.getResult();
                                System.out.println("Facebook THIS AUHTOKEN: "
                                        + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                                Intent launch = (Intent) b
                                        .get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                                if (launch != null) {
                                    startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
                                    return;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

            c = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(acct,
                    "com.facebook.auth.token.secret" /*
                                                             * what goes here
                                                             */, null, this,
                    new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                            try {
                                Bundle b = arg0.getResult();
                                System.out.println("Facebook THIS AUHTOKEN: "
                                        + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                                Intent launch = (Intent) b
                                        .get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                                if (launch != null) {
                                    startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
                                    return;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

            // mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(CALL), 0);

            i++;
        }

    }

    public void tokenForTwitter() {
        Account[] accts = mAccountManager
                .getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.auth.login");
        int i = 0;
        if (accts.length > 0) {
            System.out.println("here");
            Account acct = accts[0];
            c = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(acct,
                    "com.twitter.android.oauth.token" /* what goes here */, null,
                    this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                            try {
                                Bundle b = arg0.getResult();
                                System.out.println("twitter THIS AUHTOKEN: "
                                        + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                                Intent launch = (Intent) b
                                        .get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                                if (launch != null) {
                                    startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
                                    return;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

            c = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(acct,
                    "com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret" /*
                                                             * what goes here
                                                             */, null, this,
                    new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                            try {
                                Bundle b = arg0.getResult();
                                System.out.println("twitter THIS AUHTOKEN: "
                                        + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
                                Intent launch = (Intent) b
                                        .get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                                if (launch != null) {
                                    startActivityForResult(launch, 0);
                                    return;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

            // mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(CALL), 0);

            i++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: -1 Two questions in one... For Facebook, it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `AccountManager.getAccountsByType(null)` to retrieve all accounts, and check the returned account data includes the information you need. It may simply not be exposed.

Try calling `AccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken` instead. Also, make sure your manifest has the `USE_CREDENTIALS` permission set correctly.

You can see this discussion [How to retrieve an Facebook-AuthToken from the accounts saved on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android)

But I would also suggest `Facebook SDK` with offline access permission(This permission makes the access token returned by the OAuth endpoint long-lived, otherwise auth token is valid only for 1 hour.)

Comment: It's always returning 0 results now on Android M

Answer (score 2):

You can also create intent and obtain token from facebook application

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth");
intent.putExtra("client_id", apiKey);
intent.putExtra("scope", scope);

try {
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Then `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` of you activity you can get the token using

```
data.getStringExtra("access_token");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, the facebook application part of getAuthToken is not implemented. When you decompile it, you see that it just returns null.

You should use the Facebook SDK.

Comment: its not true @antonee marthin