# How to get twitter account Details in Android

Tags: android, twitter

How can i use Account manager in android to get the twitter account i tried this

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
            Account[] accts = am.getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.oauth.token");

            Log.d("Accounts ", ""+accts.length);
            if(accts.length > 0) {
                Account acct = accts[0];
                Log.d("Account IF", ""+acct);
                am.getAuthToken(acct, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token", null, (Activity) getApplicationContext(), new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> arg0) {
                    try {
                                 Bundle b = arg0.getResult();  
                                 Log.e("TrendDroid", "THIS AUTHTOKEN: " + b.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));  
                            } catch (Exception e) {  
                                 Log.e("TrendDroid", "EXCEPTION@AUTHTOKEN");  
                            }  
                }}, null);
```

but i am getting accts length as zero how can i fix this to get the twitter account

Comment: I think I had used something like this a while back. Unfortunately the code is on a different workstation that I currently do not have access to. However, I think it should be `getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.auth.login")` instead of the the one you are using: `getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.oauth.token")`. I could confirm after I get to the workstation, but do try this modification and see if it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Twitter and facebook Authentication and Token through Android's Account Manager classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668485/how-to-retrieve-twitter-and-facebook-authentication-and-token-through-androids)

Comment: thanks Siddharth Lale i modify the code to this com.twitter.android.auth.login i can able to get auth token but i am getting exception on posting tweets how can i fix

Comment: If you need to post to Twitter, why not use the [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) library? Much simpler, plus flexible. In my opinion anyway.

Comment: can u provide any link please

Comment: It was already in the earlier comment. Here it is again: http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html

Comment: @SiddharthLele I use the twitter4j but i am getting following error in logcat                                       TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-10981ac7 4ef6906d-026b39df], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}