# Android: How to Twitter post message Through Account Manager

Tags: android, twitter, tweets

I used android account manager for twitter authorization as given in

> [How to retrieve Twitter and facebook Authentication and Token through Android's Account Manager classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668485/how-to-retrieve-twitter-and-facebook-authentication-and-token-through-androids?rq=1)

generated access token and secret in android app. but i am not able to post a tweet using those token, secret got following errors : No authentication challenges found.any solution for this

```
at:No authentication challenges found
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1b442895
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1b442895 b2b52c28-1b44286b],
statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null,
featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:200)
attwitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
attwitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.post(HttpClientWrapper.java:102)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.post(TwitterImpl.java:1929)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.updateStatus(TwitterImpl.java:433)
at com.example.sharemessageusingservice.TwitterPost$updateTwitterStatus.doInBackground      (TwitterPost.java:340)    01-30 16:50:49.907: 
at com.example.sharemessageusingservice.TwitterPost$updateTwitterStatus.doInBackground 
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)

at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
01-30
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getAuthorizationCredentialsHttpURLConnectionImpl.java:427) 
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processAuthHeader(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)

at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:356)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)

at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
t libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:134)

at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:34)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:141)
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9668485/how-to-retrieve-twitter-and-facebook-authentication-and-token-through-androids?rq=1

Comment: found solution here

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341164/twitter-authentication-through-androids-accountmanager-classes#answer-17555813