# Using Facebook Mobile authentication in browser/webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I have facebook logged into my mobile phone. My application uses a webview and in that webview there is a facebook like button. Then I click on that, it asks for login again. Cant I use my mobile's login? Cant I pass my mobiles authorization to the webview

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android) discusses using either the `AccountManager` of Android or the [Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) for doing what you want to do.