# What are values for authTokenType in the Android AccountManager getAuthToken?

Tags: android, facebook, accountmanager

The Facebook application for Android provides an authenticator for the AccountManager.
I'm trying to get the access token with the method getAuthToken, but I do not know what are the possible values for the parameter authTokenType.
What values are available for this parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate question (which doesn't have the answer, though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be possible for you to get an access token via Facebook's Authenticator, as this would constitute a fairly significant security hole.

Instead you should use the single-sign-on api described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#enablesso

The instructions there for getting started are really good.

If you really really wanted the authTokenType value facebook uses, you could probably get it by rooting your phone and reading it out of the authentication database. I don't think this will let you read any access tokens however, and this is definitely not advised for legitimate business purposes.

Comment: Why would that be a security hole? It is possible with `AccountManager `as long as you know the authTokenType (which is "ah" for "com.google")

Comment: One month later, and I can no longer remember the vector I was thinking of. I think it had something to do with issuing access tokens to random 3rd party apps indiscriminately without input from the user. But you are correct, Facebook could have set up their app to use an authTokenType. Using it successfully would require a separate installation of the facebook app. The mobile android library goes beyond this, allowing users to login via the app (if installed) or the web. By comparison, any android device should come preinstalled with google's authenticator service.

Comment: Oh I remember! The facebook login will store a private auth token for the facebook app that will persist indefinitely. This is what allows the user to stay logged into facebook on a device over a long period of time. If you could access that private auth token you would be able to do anything to the facebook user's account. This is an obvious hole. Instead, legitimate 3rd party apps should use facebook's published authentication flow.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information, decompiling the Facebook application APK shows that the server part of the getAuthToken method is not implemented.

You need to use the Facebook SDK.