# getAuthToken y Android not calling any Callback

Tags: android, accountmanager

I've got an application in Android and I'm trying to use AccountManager to get the AuthToken and do things with Facebook or Twitter. So I've got this:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.facebook.auth.login");
Bundle options = new Bundle();
Account myAccount=null;

    for (int i=0;i<accounts.length;i++) {
        if (accounts[i].type.equals("com.facebook.auth.login")) myAccount=accounts[i];
        //options.putString("facebookUser", accounts[i].name);
    }

    am.getAuthToken(
            myAccount,                     // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
            "Manage your tasks",            // Auth scope
            options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
            this,                           // Your activity
            new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
            new Handler(new OnError()));
```

My two callbacks are onTokenAcquired:

```
public class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {

@Override
public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> result) {
    try {
        Bundle bundle = result.getResult();
        Log.e("onTokenAcquired",bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN));
    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
        Log.e("onTokenAcquired","operationcanceled");
    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
        Log.e("onTokenAcquired","authenticatorexception");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("onTokenAcquired","IOException");
    }
}
}
```

and OnError:

```
public class OnError implements Callback {

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
    Log.e("onError","ERROR");
    return false;
}

}
```

I'm following the Android Developer guide (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/id-auth/authenticate.html). So, I've got two options, on error or on token acquired, in each one I've got a Log.e() to read SOMETHING, but none is being writed.

Can anybody help me? If I was getting an error or the token was not being acquired at least I would have something to work on, but I just don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

It is not totally obvious from the documentation, but the variant of getAuthToken you are calling will never call the callback if user intervention is required.  There are some workarounds here:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25473

I don't know if that is specifically the problem you're having, but it probably isn't helping.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think getAuthToken is supported with the Facebook authenticator. Also the Auth scope "Manage your tasks" that you are using is the scope for "Google Tasks" and would most likely not be the correct scope to use if getAuthToken was supported.

I suggest that you use the [Facebook SDK for Android](http://developers.facebook.com/android/) instead. With this it is very easy to get the auth token. The SDK also have a fallback for users that doesn't have the official facebook installed, or a facebook account added to the phone which is very neat.

Please see also: [How to retrieve an Facebook-AuthToken from the accounts saved on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593061/how-to-retrieve-an-facebook-authtoken-from-the-accounts-saved-on-android)